# replace content of json files

Tags: json, python-3.x

so I have 2 json file
The first json file looks like this

```
`{
"text": "Through your use of the site, you may have the opportunities to engage in commercial transactions with other users and vendors. You acknowledge that all transactions relating to any merchandise or services offered by any party, including, but not limited to the purchase terms, payment terms, warranties, guarantees, maintenance and delivery terms relating to such transactions, are agreed to solely between the seller or purchaser of such merchandize and services and you. WE MAKE NO WARRANTY REGARDING ANY TRANSACTIONS EXECUTED THROUGH, OR IN CONNECTION WITH THIS SITE, AND YOU UNDERSTAND AND AGREE THAT SUCH TRANSACTIONS ARE CONDUCTED ENTIRELY AT YOUR OWN RISK. ANY WARRANTY THAT IS PROVIDED IN CONNECTION WITH ANY PRODUCTS, SERVICES, MATERIALS, OR INFORMATION AVAILABLE ON OR THROUGH THIS SITE FROM A THIRD PARTY IS PROVIDED SOLELY BY SUCH THIRD PARTY, AND NOT BY US OR ANY OTHER OF OUR AFFILIATES.",
"section": [
  "Disclaimer of Warranties"
]


 },
  {
    "text": "Content available through this site often represents the opinions and judgments of an information provider, site user, or other person or entity not connected with us. We do not endorse, nor are we responsible for the accuracy or reliability of, any opinion, advice, or statement made by anyone other than an authorized britnex spokesperson speaking in his/her official capacity. Please refer to the specific editorial policies posted on various sections of this site for further information, which policies are incorporated by reference into these Terms of Use.",
    "section": [
      "Disclaimer of Warranties"
    ]
  }`
```

and the other json file looks like this:

```
{
    "text": "vigueur étendula création d'un organisme spécifique au sein de l'OPCO et d'une association paritaire nationale pour la mise en œuvre des garanties sociales des salariés, dénommée APNI, de construire un socle de droits collectifs en vue :",
    "section": "[]"
},
{
    "text": "– d'assurer l'eﬀectivité par la mutualisation des droits sociaux attachés aux salariés par leur mise en œuvre ;",
    "section": "[]"
},
```

I want to replace the content of "text" in first json file with content of second json file.

Please any help to do that with python.

Thanks

Comment: Read the JSON into a Python data structure. Modify the data in the data structure. Write the data structure back out as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you have it in json file you could do this:

```
import json

with open("name_file.json", 'r') as o:
    raw_json = o.read()
    python_list = json.loads(a)
```

and then you have list which you can modify easily

Comment: thank you for your help, but how I can modify the list to change the enlish content with the frech one?